# React Router Dom Not Passing State As Component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a symbol in the state so that I can render a slug page based on the prop. I am havving issues passing the state in as it breaks everything. I am using react-router-dom to navigate the pages. I have a `Link` in another file to connect the slug pages.

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <Navbar/>
     
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path='/showinvestments' element={<Protected><ShowInvestments/></Protected>}/>
        <Route path='/addinvestments' element={<Protected><Add/></Protected>}/>
        <Route path='/sell/:stockSell' element={<Protected><Sell ticker={this.state.symbol}/></Protected>}/>       
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
      </Routes>
     
    </AuthContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The Link to the slug page

```
....
<div className='col text-center d-flex ' >
          <Link to={{pathname: sellLink, state: {symbol: ticker}}}>
              <AiFillEdit className='mt-2'/>
          </Link>
</div?
....
```

The page that I am trying to render based on the props passed in

```
const Sell = ({ticker}) => {
    // const {state} = useLocation();
    // const { tic } = state;
    // console.log(tic);

    return (
      <div className='container'>
          Hello
          {ticker}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried different variants inside of `<Route>`. If I pass a string as the ticker, it prints that, I just cannot get it to pass the current state in.

Comment: I don’t think the ‘to’ prop of ‘Link’ takes an object in v6 of React Router like it did in previous versions.

Comment: @crosen9999 i changed it to `<Link to={sellLink} state={{symbol: ticker}} />` and it still didnt work.